# Bash script for nagios error: No output on stdout - works fine on command line

Tags: bash, sed, nagios

Good evening folks,

I'm trying to read the build version of an in-house built software from several remote servers and display it on Nagios

The script runs perfectly on the command line but on Nagios I'm getting this error message:

> "(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/chk_prg_version, ...) failed. errno is 2: No such file or directory"

Here's my script (without the original data, which is sensitive needless to say)

```
#!/bin/bash

#copy the file to local temp and rename it for uniqueness
sshpass -f "password" scp -r user@serverName://FileLocation/FileName /tmp/storenumber

#Scan the file and grep anything after the string Program-Version:
pversion=$(grep "Program-Version:" /tmp/MFileName | sed 's/^.*: //')

#nagios checks
if [ if the pversion matches the latest release version ]
then
    echo "OK - $pversion"
    exit 0
elif [ if the pversion is any of the previous releases ]
then
    echo "warning error message"
    exit 1
elif [ if returns a value that doesn't match any release ]
then
    echo "critical error message"
    exit 2
else
    echo "uknown"
    exit 3
fi

#delete the file
rm /tmp/storenumber
```

Comment: Are you sure your script chk_prg_version is stored to /usr/local/nagios/libexec directory?

Comment: What happens if the pipeline `sshpass -f "password" scp -r user@serverName://FileLocation/FileName /tmp/storenumber` fails?

Comment: @gile yes, it is in /usr/local/nagios/libexec - otherwise I won't be able to restart nagios service and will get an error message

Comment: @AlexP it hasn't happened so far as credentials are same across all servers; this script definitely can be and will be improved (might use ssh keys and other stuff), but for now I need to just get it up and running

Comment: And you know that the 'rm' line is never ran?

Comment: @JimBlack yes, had to add it before every "exit" now and works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer: the command had a typo that reads the plugin. It's working absolutely fine now.